# SQL Filter with same ID but different values

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, join, rdbms

I have a query that shows the results like this:

| CUSTOMER_ID | rented_car | BUY_dATE | SELL_dATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | FERRARI | 01-03-2018 | NULL |
| 002 | DODGE | 01-03-2013 | 01-02-2015 |
| 001 | FERRARI | 01-01-2017 | 02-02-2020 |
| 002 | DODGE | 01-03-2019 | NULL |
| 002 | DODGE | 01-03-2019 | 01-03-2020 |
| 003 | RENAULT | 01-03-2019 | 01-03-2020 |

the query is

```
SELECT c.customer_id, s.name as rented_car,s.buy_date, s.sell_date
FROM company c
LEFT JOIN "user" u ON u.customer_id = c.customer_id
LEFT JOIN "cars" s ON s.customer_id = c.customer_id
```

I want to get all the customer's ID that doesn't have a car rented at the moment. If I use in the where clause a code like "where sell_date IS NOT NULL" it will show me customer ID 01,02,03 and the correct answer is only Customer ID 03.

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: It seems like you want `where sell_date is NULL` but it's really hard to tell without having representation of the tables you're joining. I'm thinking you're saying that the answer should be Customer ID 003 because it's the only one that doesn't have `NULL` in the `sell_date` if so, try the `where` condition I listed above.

Comment: @DonkeyKongII  I want to have Customer ID 003 as a result because is the only one that doesn't have a car rented at the moment. All the others customer's IDs have a car rented at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a query which groups the results by CUSTOMER_ID. You can try something like this :

```
SELECT c.customer_id
  FROM company c
  LEFT JOIN "user" u ON u.customer_id = c.customer_id
  LEFT JOIN "cars" s ON s.customer_id = c.customer_id
 GROUP BY c.customer_id
HAVING NOT bool_or(daterange(s.buy_date, s.sell_date) @> Now() :: date)
```

see the test result in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=a54b700aa2dd9e428c682185e5153115).

Answer (score 0):

You can use window function to first determine which record to pick for each of the customers and then apply your where clause. Here is an example

```
WITH cte AS 
(
  SELECT c.customer_id, 
         s.name as rented_car,
         s.buy_date, 
         s.sell_date,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition BY c.customer_id ORDER BY s.buy_date DESC) AS rn
  FROM company c
  LEFT JOIN "user" u ON u.customer_id = c.customer_id
  LEFT JOIN "cars" s ON s.customer_id = c.customer_id
)
SELECT customer_id, 
       rented_car,
       buy_date, 
       sell_date
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
      AND sell_date IS NOT NULL
```